# How does CUDA profiling work "under the hood"?

Tags: cuda, profiling

Can anyone explain how the profiler works. How it measures all the time , instructions etc given the executable. I know how to run a profiler. I wanted to know its background working.

I want to develop a profiler of my own. So I need to understand how the existing profiler works.

I am provided with the executable and need to develop a profiler to profile the executable.

Comment: Naturally, you cannot measure things without changing those things(in micro-nano space). There must be some debug registers in gpu to counter that.

Comment: First of all, have you read the [Profiler User's Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html)?

Comment: Ya I have read profiler user guide. But that doesn't explain the background working of a profiler. Can anyone explain me that.

Answer (score 4):

You can start by reading the [CUPTI Documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html).

> The CUDA Profiling Tools Interface (CUPTI) enables the creation of
>   profiling and tracing tools that target CUDA applications. CUPTI
>   provides four APIs: the Activity API, the Callback API, the Event API,
>   and the Metric API. Using these APIs, you can develop profiling tools
>   that give insight into the CPU and GPU behavior of CUDA applications.
>   CUPTI is delivered as a dynamic library on all platforms supported by
>   CUDA.

And [CUPTI Metric API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/index.html#r_metric_api) is what you should read, and you should always be aware of which CUDA version is your target, because some of the API are different than the previous or the next version.

Comment: Will I be able to edit it for my purpose. Or Can I develop one on my own with the help of this.

Comment: You should read the first sentence I quoted up there. Yes you can basically do anything you want for your profiler, given that you follow the provided APIs.